# Attributes of XSD schema to referee unique ides of other element attributes

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--<!DOCTYPE bank SYSTEM "bank.dtd">-->
<bank xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="bank.xsd">

  <accounts>
    <savings_accounts>
      <savings_account id="a1" interest="0.03">
        <balance>2500</balance>
      </savings_account>

      <savings_account id="a2" interest="0.03">
        <balance>15075</balance>
      </savings_account>
    </savings_accounts>

    <checking_accounts>
      <checking_account id="a3">
        <balance>4025</balance>
      </checking_account>
      <checking_account id="a4">
        <balance>-125</balance>
      </checking_account>
      <checking_account id="a5">
        <balance>325</balance>
      </checking_account>  
    </checking_accounts>
  </accounts>

  <customers>
    <customer id="c1">
      <name>Ben Richerdson</name>
      <address>Park Drive 2</address>
    </customer>
    <customer id="c2">
      <name>Marc Wretcher</name>
      <address>Mill Drive 75</address>
    </customer>
    <customer id="c3">
      <name>Angel Steady</name>
      <address>Lake Sight 15</address>
    </customer>
  </customers>


  <customer_accounts>
    <customer_account c_id="c1" ac_id="a2"/>
    <customer_account c_id="c1" ac_id="a3"/>
    <customer_account c_id="c2" ac_id="a4"/>
    <customer_account c_id="c3" ac_id="a1"/>
    <customer_account c_id="c3" ac_id="a5"/>
  </customer_accounts>
</bank>
```

And I also wrote the appropriate XSD schema for the XML as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="bank">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="accounts">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="savings_accounts">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="savings_account" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="balance">
                                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
                                                              <xs:minInclusive value="-5000"/>
                                                            </xs:restriction>
                                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                                <xs:attribute name="interest" type="xs:double" use="required"/>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                                <xs:unique name="onesavings_accountforEachid">
                                    <xs:selector xpath="xs:savings_account"/>
                                    <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
                                </xs:unique>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="checking_accounts">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="checking_account" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="balance">
                                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
                                                                <xs:minInclusive value="-5000"/>
                                                            </xs:restriction>
                                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                                    </xs:element>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                                <xs:unique name="onechecking_accountforEachid">
                                    <xs:selector xpath="xs:checking_account"/>
                                    <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
                                </xs:unique>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="customers">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="customer" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                                        <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                    <xs:unique name="onecustomerforEachid">
                        <xs:selector xpath="xs:customer"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
                    </xs:unique>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="customer_accounts">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="customer_account" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="c_id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                    <xs:attribute name="ac_id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

So my question is, how can I refere the c_id="c1" and ac_id="a2" of customer_account to the appropriate id as defined in accounts. 'c_id' refers to customers and 'ac_id' refers to accounts.

I was looking it is possible to do the same but instead I have to add id's as elements and define them as private key and later foreign key.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking for a way to ensure that

- For every value of attribute `customer_account/@c_id`, there is exactly one customer with that value as the value of its @id attribute.
- For every value of attribute `customer_account/@ac_id`, there is exactly one account (either a checking or a savings account) with that value as the value of its @id attribute.
- No two customers have the same @id value.
- No two savings accounts have the same @id value.
- No two checking accounts have the same @id value.

The last three constraints are already enforced by the `unique` elements you have included in the elements `savings_accounts`, `checking_accounts`, and `customers`.

If that's a correct understanding of what you are trying to achieve, then:

- If you want to ensure that any value of `customer_account/@ac_id` matches exactly one account, you need to ensure that no checking account has the same id as any savings account.  Right now, you allow savings and checking accounts to share IDs.  You'll need to add a `unique` (or `key`) constraint on `accounts` that covers both forms of account. The following should do it:

  ```
  <xs:unique name="oneaccountforEachid">
    <xs:selector xpath="*/*"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
  </xs:unique>
  ```
- You want to define two `keyref` elements specifying that the c_id and a_id attributes on element `customer_account` refer successfully to keys of customers and accounts.  This can go on the `customer_account` element, if you prefer:

  ```
  <xs:keyref refer="onecustomerforEachid" 
             name="ca_customer_pointer" >
    <xs:selector xpath="."/>
    <xs:field xpath="@c_id"/>
  </xs:keyref>
  <xs:keyref refer="oneaccountforEachid" 
             name="ca_account_pointer">
    <xs:selector xpath="."/>
    <xs:field xpath="@ac_id"/>
  </xs:keyref>
  ```

  Speaking for myself, I think the schema might be clearer if all of the identity constraints were on the `bank` element:

  ```
  <xs:element name="bank" type="bank">
    <xs:unique name="account_id_unique">
      <xs:selector xpath="accounts/*/*"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="customer_id_unique">
      <xs:selector xpath="customers/customer"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:keyref name="ca_customer_id"
               refer="customer_id_unique">
      <xs:selector 
        xpath="customer_accounts/customer_account"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@c_id"/>
    </xs:keyref>
    <xs:keyref name="ca_account_id" 
               refer="account_id_unique">
      <xs:selector 
        xpath="customer_accounts/customer_account"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@ac_id"/>
    </xs:keyref>
  </xs:element>
  ```

Additionally, you may wish to change your existing `unique` elements to be `key` elements, to stress that each customer and account is required to have an @id.  One short description of the difference is:  the `unique` constraints you have (or those shown) say that if an @id attribute appears on the indicated elements, its value must be unique among the @id values on those elements.  A `key` constraint requires the same thing, and further requires that all the elements in question should in fact *have* an @id attribute.  Since you already require the @id attribute (via its declaration), the two have the same effect in this case.